# Looking for a book on the historic development of halakhah

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books

Would anyone be able to recommend a good intermediate level book-length treatment of the development of halakhah from the second temple period down to the present day, ideally in English?

I am interested in coming to a better understanding of the role of the different rishonim and acheronim in the development of halakha. Most introductions to the topic that I have read seem to touch on only Talmud, Mishneh Torah and Shulkan Aruch and then go no further, whereas I would like to learn more and in reasonable depth about the scholars whose names I keep encountering e.g. Rif, Rosh, Shakh and Chazon Ish, to name a few.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I think you will enjoy [The History and Process of Halacha](http://eretzhemdah.org/Data/UploadedFiles/SitePages/273-sFileRedirEn.pdf), a 17-page intro to Eretz Hemda' Living the Halachic Process which covers exactly the topics you ask

Comment: Thank you. That looks like a great resource. I shall read it with interest.

Comment: Rabbi Natan Lopez Cardozo has a book on this called "The Written and Oral Law: A Comprehensive Introduction"; I can't verify that he covers specifically what the OP asks in the question.

Comment: Thanks! I see that is on kindle so I shall have a look.

Comment: Aryeh Kaplan’s handbook covers it

Comment: Not book length but [this](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9673-law-codification-of) is a highly recommended essay on this topic, by Prof. [Louis Ginzberg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Ginzberg).

Answer (score 2):

A very thorough book that is probably what you might be looking for: 
The Halakhah It's Sources and Development EPHRAIM URBACH ההלכה - מקורותיה והתפתחותה